# Java - Playing a sound on JButton Hover/Click/Released

Tags: java, swing, audio

I've been writing a Launcher for Minecraft using the source code of Technic, and I've managed to make a pretty nifty looking fork of it.

In order to make the launcher a little more unique, aside from altering the appearance, I decided to add a sound API that allows me to play a *.wav, *.ogg file when I hover/click/release a button in the launcher. I'm using my own components, but they extend the Swing components, so I have access to the mouseClicked, mousePressed, mouseReleased, mouseEntered, mouseExited events within my code.

I've had a look at several different examples of adding sound to a Java application, and I've attempted to tweak it to suit my application. But no luck.

This is my source for the AudioAPI class:

```
package uk.co.roguerage.launcher.main.ui.components.api;

import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class AudioAPI {
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    private SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    public void playAudio(File soundFile) {
        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();

            System.out.println(audioFormat);

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            new PlayThread().start();
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class PlayThread extends Thread {
    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    public void run() {
        try {
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();

            int cnt;

            while( (cnt = audioInputStream.read(tempBuffer,0,tempBuffer.length)) != -1 ) {
                if( cnt > 0 ) {
                    sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                }
            }

            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I call the API using the following code:

```
AudioAPI audioAPI = new AudioAPI();
audioAPI.playAudio(soundHover);
```

All I seem to get is an error whenever I hover over the buttons. This is the error:

```
[B#1] java.lang.NullPointerException
[B#1]   at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at uk.co.roguerage.launcher.main.ui.components.api.AudioAPI.playAudio(AudioAPI.java:18)
[B#1]   at uk.co.roguerage.launcher.main.ui.components.LiteButton.mouseEntered(LiteButton.java:88)
[B#1]   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[B#1]   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[B#1]   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
[B#1]   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is soundHover pointing to?  It's saying the sound is null, so are you sure you're calling the file correctly?

Comment: soundHover is pointing to the following: `private File soundHover = ResourceUtils.getResourceAsFile("/uk/co/roguerage/launcher/main/resources/sounds/button_hover.wav");`

Answer (score 1):

I would fish for cause at line `audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);` and would start with verifying that file is ok (just because you created `File` object it does not mean that it is associeated with actual file), if it points to REAL file in file system. Morever, do you want to read the file from filesystem every time you hover over the button. Don't you want to store the data into memory?